# Error when installing Git

Tags: macos, git, terminal

I am using Mac 10.5.8. I am following this tutorial: [1]: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git . I have a problem with: git credential-osxkeychain . The Terminal shows me the following error:

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022


error: git-credential-osxkeychain died of signal 5
```

Could anyone help me to solve this problem? What is the matter with this key?

Comment: Is this the result of running `git credential-osxkeychain` or did you add some arguments to that? Is there a reason you would prefer to use git over https to git over ssh w/ keypair auth?

Comment: I did not add any argument to this. This is the result of running that that command. I am getting stuck in that point and do not know whether or not git has been installed. Could you please help to install it successfully. According to the tutorial, that command is for Password caching.

Comment: It's not a required part of using git and is only applicable when using URLs like `https://github.com/user/repo.git` and not for URLs like `git@github.com:user/repo.git`. Personally, I prefer the latter style, which uses your public/private keypair instead of a user/pass. Did you install git via Xcode's "Command Line Tools" component?

Comment: No, I did not. I installed it via Terminal in mac.

Comment: What command did you use to install it? I would recommend you launch Xcode, and go to `Preferences... -> Downloads -> Components` and install `Command Line Tools`.

Comment: I think this tutorial [http://shaun.boyblack.co.za/blog/2009/03/14/getting-started-with-git-on-mac-os-x/] is quite useful.

Comment: My mac is 10.5.8. I do not think this platform suits Xcode

Comment: You can download Xcode 3.1.4 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads but will need to log in with a (free) developer account.

Comment: Will try it and let you know.